# Why ajax receive different values than send from php controller

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with ajax response which is sent by php controller.

I have got these code in my php controller:
[image: php controller]

ajax_return_success is my function where i just json_encode my function argument.

When ajax is set to dataType: json it throws exceptions or receive NaN (depending on what data type is sent). I checked what is in $result and there is similar to $output. But when I change $result to $output in ajax_return_success everything runs smooth and good.

When ajax is set to dataType: text it shows that in response is:

`{"STATUS":"OK","MESSAGE":["0","0","0","0"]}`

But what it should looks like:

```
{"STATUS":"OK","MESSAGE":["2","1","1","6"]}
```

Have anybody encountered that problem ? What cause that difference in what i send and what i receive. I want to ensure that ajax_return_success works good because it is used in many places but there is something not ok.

P.S When I use Postman to send request everything is always fine. Problem is with standard ajax.

Comment: Hi, Thank You for Your help very much but i solved my problem by selecting data which i needed from database. Maybe this is stupid because firstly i put data in database and immidiately select it from it, but because some strange reasons i cannot use data which i have available in my code :/ Anyway i need this data in database but it is unefficient. It is possible that this problem is caused by encoding of php file or something simmilar ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found the answer already! I have got errors notification shut off in my codeigniter and in one place in one function i have divided by 0. Unfortunately php dont give ... anything about it and continue, but ajax for some reason have strange behaviour. Today i have simmilar problem because for some, undefined reason ajax show error even that http status was 200.

And after debugging it shows off that dividing by 0 it is not a good idea ;)

Comment: Could You tell me what is wrong with my answer ? I will improve my answer, i promise ;)